# hash tables alignment not working

Tags: powershell

since I added this code ('cause with 2 floats is enough for me) my hashtables get's desaligned. thanks in advance.

```
@{Name="Megas";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f $($_.Length / 1MB)}}
```

from orignal

```
@{Name="Megas";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB}}
```

Desired output:

```
Ficheros                                 Megas(top rigth)
--------                                 ----- 
\desktop\someting.exe                    1.20
```

Actual output, is causing inclompete paths...

```
Ficheros              Megas(at the middle)
--------              ----- 
\desktop\sometin...   1.20
```

CODE:

```
param([string]$pc,[string]$user)

$w7="\\$pc\c$\users\$user\desktop"
if(Test-Path $w7){

    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -force -Include *.* -exclude *.ini, *.lnk, *.url, *.db, *.txt $w7 -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" | ls | Select-Object -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" @{Name="Ficheros";Expression={$_.FullName -replace '.*?(\\Desktop.*)', '$1'}}, @{Name="Megas";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB}}

}

else{
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Red "FAIL"
}
```

I tried with, but get the error "The align directive is not supported for hashtables used with Select-Object....etc"

```
Select-Object format-table @{Name="Megas";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB};alignment="right"}
```

Comment: Does it format it like you want if you add |format-table -auto at the end of that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AdilHindistan has suggested in a comment, you should try to use `Format-Table -AutoSize` to fix the visual output. `Select-Object` is used to extract(create a custom object) with only the properties you need before exporting objects etc. `Format-Table` is what you should use when you need to create a customized view for "visual results". So try:

```
param([string]$pc,[string]$user)

$w7="\\$pc\c$\users\$user\desktop"
if(Test-Path $w7){

    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -force -Include *.* -exclude *.ini, *.lnk, *.url, *.db, *.txt -Path $w7 -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" |
    Format-Table -AutoSize -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" @{Name="Ficheros";Expression={$_.FullName -replace '.*?(\\Desktop.*)', '$1'}}, @{Name="Megas";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB}}
}

else{
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Red "FAIL"
}
```

You also had an unnecessary `ls(Get-ChildItem)`in your sample. You're already using `-Recurse` in your first `Get-ChildItem` call.